# Error trying to replace Vimeo file using Python library

Tags: python, vimeo-api

I am using the Vimeo Python Library [example](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries/examples/python#:%7E:text=Replacing%20a%20video%20source%20file).  After setting up a simple example, I am getting an error below.  Do I need to create a new token?

**Error**

```
window.vimeo.exception_data = {"title":"Unauthorized","message":"Oops! This action could not be completed because your form session expired. Please make sure your cookies are enabled, then return to the previous page and try again.","notification":null,"search":true,"videos":null,"ad_config":{"house_ads_enabled":false},"page_type":"exception","module_type":"standard_multi"};
```

**CODE**

```
import vimeo
import os


VIMEO_TOKEN=os.environ.get("TOKEN")
VIMEO_KEY=os.environ.get("KEY")
VIMEO_SECRET=os.environ.get("SECRET")


client = vimeo.VimeoClient(
    token=VIMEO_TOKEN,
    key=VIMEO_KEY,
    secret=VIMEO_SECRET
)



video_uri = client.replace(
                'https://vimeo.com/745944239',
                'test_replace_test.mov'
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the video's API URI, something to the effect of

`client.replace('/videos/745944239', 'file_to_replace.mov')`